# R -Same output for each line in column specified function

Tags: r

I have a rather basic problem, but hope to find some help here. I am extracting data from a dataframe "maindata" using coordinates in a dataframe "norm_regions" from which I then want to calculate the median value for each line in "norm_regions":

```
normalize_data <- function(maindata, norm_regions){
  norm_regions[,1]<-factor(norm_regions[,1], levels=levels(straindata[,3]))
  norm_regions$median<-call_region_median(straindata, chrom=norm_regions$chrom, start=norm_regions$start, end=norm_regions$end)
  return(norm_regions)
}

call_region_median <- function(maindata, chrom, start, end) {
  region<-subset(straindata, V3==chrom & V4>=start & V4<=end)
  region_median<-median(region$V5, na.rm=TRUE)
  return(region_median)
}
```

Strangely, I get the same output for all the coordinates, while when I do it for each coordinate one by one, this is not the case:

```
chrom  start    end    median
1  chrXII 373029 373529  144.7
2  chrVII 888228 888728  144.7
3    chrV  93848  94348  144.7
4    chrX 683618 684118  144.7
5   chrVI 199188 199688  144.7
6   chrIX 411686 412186  144.7
7  chrIII  74318  74818  144.7
8  chrXIV 561002 561502  144.7
9   chrXV 277405 277905  144.7
10   chrI 176029 176529  144.7
```

What is the issue here?

edit:
Here an example of norm_regions:

```
chrom   start   end
chrXII  373029  373529
chrVII  888228  888728
chrV    93848   94348
chrX    683618  684118
chrVI   199188  199688
```

And of maindata:

```
V1    V2    V3    V4    V5
WT  brdu    chrI    1   33.44
WT  brdu    chrI    2   34.91
WT  brdu    chrI    3   35.51
WT  brdu    chrI    4   39.78
```

Comment: what's `straindata`?

Comment: Sorry, should be maindata as well.